# Difference is spaces when using \t

Tags: python

When tried running the following codes and the results were different than what I expected:

```
print ("\\"*6,"\tHello World!\t","\\"*6)
print ("\\\\\\\\\\\\\tHello World!\t\\\\\\\\\\\\")
```

I expected both codes to have 6 backslashes, a tab space, Hello World!, a tab space and six backslashes. But the 1st line has more space than the 2nd line on the final 6 backslashes. Anyone know why?

Here's the output:

```
\\\\\\  Hello World!     \\\\\\
\\\\\\  Hello World!    \\\\\\
```

Comment: You're just seeing that print("a", "b") adds a space between "a" and "b".

Comment: `print(1, 2)` also doesn't give you `12` but `1 2`.

Comment: @Demi-Lune but why is the space between the first 6 backslashes and hello equal since that part also has a comma

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [print() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) shows the reason. `print()` takes any number of argument, and output them in the console separated by default by the space `' '` character.
If you modify you first line like this :

```py
print ("\\"*6,"\tHello World!\t","\\"*6, sep='')
```

You'll get the same result

Comment: but why is the default space not present in the first part of the output between the first 6 backslashes and hello as they appear equal in the output.

Comment: @Puna I think its because the space is "eaten" by the tab, I tested like this     
```print ("\\"*6,"  Hello World!\t","\\"*6)``` and  
```print ("\\\\\\\\\\\\  Hello World!\t\\\\\\\\\\\\")
```
and got the space both in the first and second part

Comment: see [this answer on quora](https://qr.ae/pKfARw) about the ```\t``` char. It advances to the next stop, not by a fixed amount of space, so if there is a tab stop every two space, and you print ```' '\t```, the tab will only advance one space